# Двумерный массив в C++

Tags: c++, c, динамические-массивы

Занялся изучением плюсов после трех лет Java (Android)
Динамическое выделение памяти

```
 int N = 2;
int **M = (int **) malloc(N * sizeof(int));
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    M[i] = (int *) malloc(N * sizeof(int));
}
```

После такого создания получаю массив указателей M, у которого дебагер (в CLion) выдает нескончаемое количество элементов. И каждый из элементов содержит нескончаемое количетсво интов.Точнее, указателей на них 
Объясните, пожалуйста, что за количество элементов такое? От значения N количество не меняется. Это указатели на память за пределами массивов?

Comment: Как рекомендация - в большинстве случаев нет смысла вручную выделять/освобождать память. Для тех же массивов есть `std::vector` и `std::array`.

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос к дебагеру: что он там показывает. Фактически, `М` - просто указатель, наверное поэтому и нет у него какого-то определенного размера, доступного дебагеру.

Попробуйте объявить именно массив и посмотреть, что он на это скажет:

```
int K[42];
```

При этом в коде у Вас ошибка. В первом выделении должно быть `sizeof(int*)`. Ну и в добавок, плюсами тут не пахнет. Чистые Си.

Answer (score 2):

`malloc` и `free` в C++ не используют - они не совместимы с "родными" `new` и `delete`. Если что-то выделить через `malloc`, а удалить через `delete`, будет UB. Поэтому, надежнее от этой парочки просто отказаться. Тем более, дурацкая чехарда с размерами - нафиг-нафиг.

"Правильное" с точки зрения стандарта и чистоты кода изготовление двумерного массива:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using std::vector;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main() 
{
    constexpr size_t M=10; //count of rows
    constexpr size_t N=12; //count of cols
    constexpr int v=42;    //initial value
    vector<vector<int>> alpha(
        M, //count of rows
        vector<int>(   //initial row
                     N,  //count of cols
                     v   //initial value
                    ) 

        );
    for(const auto& i:alpha)
    {
        for(const auto& j:i)
        {
            cout << j << ' ';
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/o0HWZo)